# How can I refactor a Rails Controller action to eliminate clutter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refactoring, instance-variables

I have an action called `update_mobile` and in it I am preparing a massive amount of instance variables that I use in a RABL JSON request. You can see that if the request contains the `params[:last_updated]` parameter, then I only get the models that have been updated since then. This seems to disobey the "Fat Models, Skinny Controllers" method. How can I refactor this method?

```
  def update_mobile
    @last_updated = params[:last_updated]
    if @last_updated.nil?
      @buddies = @user.friends
      @courses = @user.courses
      @friendly_schools = @user.friendly_schools
      @documents = @user.all_notes
      @instructors = @user.current_instructors
      @friendships = @user.friendships
      @questions = @user.current_questions
      @answers = @user.current_answers
      @comments = @user.current_comments
    else
      @buddies = @user.friends.select{ |user| user.updated_at > @last_updated }
      @courses = @user.courses.select{ |course| course.updated_at > @last_updated }
      @friendly_schools = @user.friendly_schools.select{ |school| school.updated_at > @last_updated }
      @documents = @user.all_notes.select{ |note| note.updated_at > @last_updated }
      @instructors = @user.current_instructors.select{ |instructor| instructor.updated_at > @last_updated }
      @friendships = @user.friendships.select{ |friendship| friendship.updated_at > @last_updated }
      @questions = @user.current_questions.select{ |question| question.updated_at > @last_updated }
      @answers = @user.current_answers.select{ |answer| answer.updated_at > @last_updated }
      @comments = @user.current_comments.select{ |comment| comment.updated_at > @last_updated }
    end
  end
```

Comment: I'm not really good in rails. So take this advice with caution: You could create a method in the model `def self.since_latest` and return a hash with the different collections from that method: `{:buddies => friends.select {...}, :courses => ....`. 
You could also pass along `@last_updated` and let the method in the model select which entries are returned

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should move the code out to your model and let your model deal with 1) the parameter being `nil` and 2) using ActiveRecord to query the database effectively.

In your controller, have lines like this for each of your variables:

```
@friends = @user.friends.updated_since(params[:last_updated])
```

*(I've renamed `@buddies` here to `@friends`, because we want to maintain consistency in naming the things of the system)*

Then, in your `Friend` model, define a class method called `updated_since` that does that logic:

```
class Friend < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.updated_since(last_updated)
    if last_updated.present?
      where("updated_at > ?", last_updated)
    else
      all
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Does a method like this already exist in Rails? Wouldn't it be best to add an `updated_since` method to `ActiveRecord::Base` or another module that all models inherit from?

Comment: Cool. Your answer means I wasn't too far off with my comment.

Comment: @ardavis: No there is no method like that in Rails as far as I know. You can move the code into a module, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using rails 4.x then the cleanest way to do this is through [Concerns](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html). Instead of copy & pasting the same scope throughout every model, you can create a general scope and simply include it in the models that its needed.

**Updated since concern**:

```
# my_app/app/models/concerns/updated_since.rb
module UpdatedSince
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def updated_since(time)
      if parsed_time = convert_time(time)
        where("updated_at >= ?", parsed_time)
      else
        all
      end
    end

    private

      def convert_time(time)
        Time.zone.parse(time) unless time.blank?
      rescue ArgumentError
        self.logger.warn "Invalid updated_since time: <#{time}>"
        nil
      end
  end
end
```

**Include it in the relevant models:**

```
class Friend < ActiveRecord::Base
  include UpdatedSince
end
```

**Use it in your controller:**

```
@friends = @user.friends.updated_since(params[:last_updated])
```